# When is a thick subcategory the preimage of a weak Serre class under a homological functor?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories, abelian-categories

Let $\pi : \mathcal T \to \mathcal A$ be a [homological functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homological+functor) from a stable / triangulated category to an abelian category, and let $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal A$ be a [*weak* Serre subcategory](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02MN). Let $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal C) \subseteq \mathcal T$ be the full subcategory of objects $T$ such that $\pi(\Sigma^n T) \in \mathcal C$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$. Then $\pi^{-1}(\mathcal C)$ is a thick subcategory of $\mathcal T$ ("by construction" -- this is kind of the whole point of weak Serre classes!)

**Question:** Suppose that $\mathcal P \subseteq \mathcal T$ is a thick subcategory of a stable / triangulated category $\mathcal T$. Under what conditions does there exist an abelian category $\mathcal A$, a homological functor $\pi : \mathcal T \to \mathcal A$, and a weak Serre class $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal A$ such that $\mathcal P = \pi^{-1}(\mathcal C)$?

I'm also interested in the version of this question where $\mathcal T$ is compactly-generated, $\mathcal A$ is required to be Grothendieck, and $\mathcal \pi$ is required to commute with filtered colimits.

**EDIT:** I realize that when $\mathcal P$ is closed under colimits, then it's fruitful to think of this question in terms of the localization $\mathcal T / \mathcal P$. But, as I should have specified, this question is motivated primarily by the case where $\mathcal P$ is a thick subcategory which is *not* closed under coproducts -- in fact, I'd be happy to restrict to the case where $\mathcal P$ is *small*. For example, consider the case where $\mathcal T$ is the category of spectra and $\mathcal P$ is the full subcategory of finite-type spectra. Then $\mathcal P = \pi^{-1}(\mathcal F)$, where $\pi : \mathcal T \to Ab$ takes homotopy groups, and $\mathcal F \subset Ab$ is the full subcategory of finitely-generated abelian groups. I'm wondering to what extent one can understand small thick subcategories in terms of homological functors.

Comment: An example of $\mathcal P$ which is of the above form is the thick subcategory of $p$-complete spectra sitting among all spectra; here $\pi : Spt \to Ab$ takes stable homotopy groups and $\mathcal C \subset Ab$ comprises the $p$-local, cotorsion abelian groups. I'm a bit confused now, but I think maybe one gets thick subcategories not obviously of this form from chromatic homotopy theory?

Comment: Are you willing to pass to a larger universe?:) Then you can just take $\mathcal{C}=0$, $\mathcal{A}$ to be abelian groups,  and consider  the product of  functors that are corepresentable in the quotient $\mathcal{T}/\mathcal{P}$.  I can say more about this recipe in the compactly generated setting.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Oh... I would indeed be willing to pass to a larger universe. I'd be very interested to hear what you have to say

Answer (score 1):

"Almost certainly" (as far as I remember, one needs either a set of generators for  $\mathcal P$ or the Vopenka principle; see Theorem 7.2.1 of Krause's https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1324) if $\mathcal{P}$ is closed with respect to $\mathcal{T}$-coproducts then the Verdier quotient $\mathcal{T}/\mathcal{P}$ is locally small and well generated.
Thus if $L:\mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{T}/\mathcal{P}$ is the localization functor then you can compose it

(i) either with the collection of functors corepresentable by the corresponding generators. This will give a collection of functors into abelian groups whose kernel is $\mathcal{P}$. Unfortunately, these functors do not have to respect coproducts.

(ii) or with the functor into the category $\hat{\mathcal{S}}$ of coherent functors, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the $\coprod$-closure in $\mathcal{T}/\mathcal{P}$ of a perfect set of generators $\mathcal{S}_0$; see  Krause's https://eudml.org/doc/49219. You will obtain a functor that respect coproducts and whose target is AB4.

I don't know how to respect coproducts and make the target Grothendieck abelian simultaneously, sorry. Possibly, Krause's papers on localizations contain a solution.:)

Comment: So, I suspect that you will not obtain many new examples if you take $\mathcal{C}$ that is not zero.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's enlightening! I realize now I should stress that I'm particularly interested in examples of $\mathcal P$ which are _not_ closed under small coproducts, such as when $\mathcal P \subset Spt$ comprises the spectra of finite type. I will edit to clarify this.

Comment: Anyway, your $\mathcal{P}$ should be closed with respect to the operations $X\mapsto \coprod_i X[s_i]$, where $|s_i|\to \infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- if $X$ is of finite type but unbounded below, then $\amalg_i X[s_i]$ is not of finite type for suitable $|s_i| \to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry; it appears that I made a mistake.